# Toggle button on modeline

Tags: mode-line, mode-line-format

How to create a toggle button in the modeline, like a play / pause button ? 
for now, I've got the following :

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
      '(
    (:eval
      (propertize
      " ⏸ "
        'local-map (make-mode-line-mouse-map 'mouse-1 'helm-spotify-plus-toggle-play-pause)
      )
    )

))
```

And I would like to toggle play and pause unicode characters.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have much experience customizing the mode line, but the following seems working from here. It displays the status of `column-number-mode` using `ON` and `OFF`, when you click the text, the mode will be toggled and the text will be updated as well.

```
(defvar mode-line-column-number-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [mode-line mouse-1]
      (lambda (_e)
        (interactive "e")
        (column-number-mode 'toggle)))
    map))

(setq mode-line-format
      '((:eval (propertize (if column-number-mode "On" "Off")
                           'local-map mode-line-column-number-map))
        (column-number-mode "  %c")))
```

Comment: I've just tested it, it works, thanks, I'll also post my own solution and I'd like you or other people to review / criticize it because I'm new to lisp and I don't know if it's a good way to do the thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution I found, don't know if it's the right way, but it works :

```
(defvar music-paused nil)

(setq-default mode-line-format '(
  (:eval (if (eq music-paused t)
    (propertize " ⏸ " 'local-map (make-mode-line-mouse-map 'mouse-1 '(lambda () (setq music-paused nil)) ))
    (propertize " ⏵ " 'local-map (make-mode-line-mouse-map 'mouse-1 '(lambda () (setq music-paused t)) ))
  ))
))
```